# Apple Associated Domains and Shared Web Credentials

Tags: ios, xcode, credentials, associated-domains

For authentication in my iOS application, I want to use the Apple Shared Web Credentials feature.

I have put an associated domain file on my website. This file is accessible under the path https://subdomain.domain.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association and has the following content:

```
{
  "webcredentials": {
    "apps": [
      "XXXXXXXX.demo.App"
    ]
  }
}
```

I enabled the Associated Domains capability in my iOS application and added the following entry there:

> webcredentials:subdomain.domain.com

[image]

Now I build and launch the application and get the login screen. As soon as I enter the login data there and submit, I get the following error:

> **Application with identifier XXXXXXXX.demo.App is not associated with domain subdomain.domain.com**

Does the iOS application use the configured associated domain to make the query of the file on the web server? What exactly am I missing here?

Answer (score -2):

Kindly note some points in order to make it work :

- that you must replace XXXXX with your teamId from your apple developer account, and other part is you bundle identifier.
- Apple’s content delivery network requests the apple-app-site-association file for your domain **within 24 hours**. Devices check for updates approximately once per week after app installation, so you may require re-install the app after any edits to the apple-app-site-association file.
- you may have to enable (autofill credential provider) capability in order to use credentials in authFillPassword ui.
- set the attribute textContentType to make system identify the input as (username,email, passsord .... etc).

References:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains#Add-the-associated-domains-entitlement-to-your-app

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill